# How often do popular academic books use unacknowledged ghost writers and is this a form of fraud or plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism, books, outreach

My impression is that the use of ghostwriters is common and sort of accepted / an open secret in some contexts (e.g. books by celebrities or politicians).  I'm curious if others have that impression, but that's not my main question...

My question is about academics writing books meant to popularize ideas from their discipline.  Under what conditions would this would be viewed similarly, viewed as less-virtuous-but-still-acceptable, viewed as unacceptable/fraudulent/plagiarism, etc.

I'm thinking of books like "The Selfish Gene", "A Brief History of Time", or "What Money Can't Buy: The Moral Limits of Markets".  EtA: these are purely hypothetical examples.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this question, but I'm also wondering if you can point to any evidence of ghostwriting, e.g. a case that's well-known? I've never heard the ghost of a whisper that *Selfish Gene* or *Brief History of TIme* were ghost-written. (*Freakonomics*, for example, is an *open* collaboration between an economist (Levitt) and a journalist (Dubner)).

Comment: There isn’t a ghostwriter in existence who could have written any of the books in your example. The nature of these books is that they are the distillation of some academic’s entire career of thinking deeply about a subject. Writing something like this is not some kind of grunt work you can delegate to a shadow person. Conversely, academics who have something interesting to say are perfectly capable of writing their own book, and don’t need a ghostwriter in the way that a business person, athlete or celebrity does. So basically this question is based on a false premise.

Comment: @DanRomik using a ghost writer doesn't mean that you don't contribute any of the content yourself.  See Freakonomics and others (Book of Why) for counterexamples to your comment.

Comment: @capybaralet those aren’t counterexamples. They do not involve a ghostwriter.

Comment: @DanRomik I think a ghostwriter is not necessarily somebody who writes the whole book, but somebody whose contribution merits authorship but is not listed as an author. That these authors decided to collaborate with journalists in writing these books indicates to me that they found it useful and were able to delegate significant parts of the process to another author.  This is why I say it is a country example to what you said in your comment.

Comment: @capybaralet sounds like you're moving the goalposts of your question. Well, anyway, I've stated my opinion and stand by it. I don't have anything to add at this point.